# openoffice ole automation

Tags: c#, automation, ole, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to automate openoffice calc through ole automation from a c# application. I'm opening a document and saving it again. Code is mostly downloaded from Apache web site with few modifications.

```
    private void OpenSave(string FileAddress)//format: "file:///C:/Untitled1.ods"
    {
        Type t_OOo= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("com.sun.star.ServiceManager");
        Object objServiceManager= System.Activator.CreateInstance(t_OOo);

        // arguments for IDispatch-call 
        Object[] parameters = new Object[1];
        parameters[0] = "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop";

        // arguments for document 
        Object[] args = new Object[4];
        //args[0] = "private:factory/scalc";
        args[0] = FileAddress;         
        args[1] = "_blank";
        args[2] = 0;
        args[3] = new Object[] { };

        Object desktop;
        Object doc;
        try
        {
            desktop = (Object)t_OOo.InvokeMember("createInstance",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,objServiceManager, parameters);
            doc = desktop.GetType().InvokeMember("loadComponentFromUrl",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, desktop, args);

            if (doc == null)
            {/*Error*/ }

            object[] O = new object[3];
            O[0] = FileAddress;
            O[1] = new PropertyValue();
            ((PropertyValue)O[1]).Name = "";
            ((PropertyValue)O[1]).Value = true;
            O[2] = new Object[] { };

            desktop.GetType().InvokeMember("storeAsURL", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, desktop,O);            
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e1);
        }
```

Last line of code (saveTOURL) always throws exception of "Unknown name"(exact exception: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"}). May Anybody help? Please consider that I'm mostly opening xls files with this program.

In fact documentation about c# & OLE is not rich enough. All documentation is in Java and I had to compare Java to few ole samples available to find a weak clue about object model.

I want to be able to modify a cell's value before saving, I would be grateful if you could guide me about this one also.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: All right, people like me who rarely post here may forget this behavior code after a while because it's not similar to usual etiquette, I will try to keep it in mind.

Comment: I hoped somebody would help here. Is it acceptable if I directly ask a person who has answered similar question to take a look at my problem?

Comment: No, that's not acceptable. You should assume that those people have seen your question, and have decided not to answer it. One reason might be that you have not supplied us with the full exception. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using c# SDK instead of OLE, so this is not exactly answer to question about OLE.

I recommend using SDK because you can benefit the predefined object model of official API while in com interop there is no such guide.

You must have Openoffice SDK installed on your system, then in your c# project add reference to all dlls in this directory:

...\OpenOffice 4\sdk\cli\cli_basetypes.dll

These pages have practical samples of using APIs of c#:

http://suite101.com/a/creating-an-openoffice-calc-document-with-c-a124112 (404)
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=107055

Comment: The links are dead, as to be expected. Now it would be nice to see a few lines of example code..